# About python dir() function

Tags: python

[image]

There's a folder called **models**, and there's a **conduct.ipynb** file. And in the folder called **models**, there's a file called **MMM.py** . There is a Class called **user** on **MMM.py** (Class name is "user").

I did **import models** in **conduct.ipynb** and did **dir(models)**. Here, I want the list returned from **dir(models)** to contain the Class **user**. However, **dir(models)** does not return the class user.

Should I lower the python version? What should I do?

Comment: `from models import MMM; print(dir(MMM))`

Comment: Your `user` class is not directly under `models`, so it will not show up with `dir(models)`. You need to call `dir` directly on the parent/enclosing module/package. Or, are you expecting `dir` to be recursive, such that it goes inside each sub-module?

Comment: Is this the only way? It's because I have a special reason to import models and get class name through dir(models).

Comment: What do you actually need: strictly just the _name_ "user" string from the `dir` output OR being able to actually _import_ the class `user` from `models`?

Comment: Now it sounds like an [x y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).